# Suggest me solution to track the change in test DB and replicate in Another DB

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

Suggest me solution to track the change in test DB and replicate in Another DB...

My Client need a script or any solution, if he has two Database, One Test DB in which he tests his data on test portal and if he find it appropriate he can use those changes to be done in main DB to display on Live site.. Fior this he needs the solution to record or track all updation/deletion/insertion, so that he can do the same in main DB if found appropriate,

```
NOTE:
```

we have only one server, no separate server, hence binary log replication doesnt seems to be working for my case..

Answer (score 1):

You could turn on the query log and then you have a record of all queries run against the DB. The file is plain text so you could then cut and paste the queries you want.

If you wanted to replicate every query to another database, you could run "test" on another MySQL instance say port 3307 using mysql_multi on the same physical box, then "live" could be a slave of "test".